# Events.list: singleEvents Setting not Respected for freeBusyReader calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I noticed today that when calling [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) with `singleEvents` explicitly set to `false` with an account with freeBusyReader credentials doesn't return recurring events according to the singleEvents parameter provided. Namely, recurring events are expanded to instance events regardless of the option. This is surprising to me for two reasons:

1) When fetching the master event directly with [Events.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get), the master event is visible to the freeBusyReader account with the recurrence rule displayed.

2) We haven't noticed this behavior until today.

Wanted to see if anyone had experience with this -- is this a regression/bug or is the documentation here just lacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was already reported on [***Google Issue Tracker***](https://issuetracker.google.com).

You can see it [***HERE***](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145286489).

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't reported yet (I had searched for it) when I opened this question initially.